# How to add "related products" in Woocommerce Customer Mails

Tags: php, wordpress, email, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I want to display 4 related products in Woocommerce Customer Mails but when I simply call the shortcode inside the `customer-processing-order.php` nothing happens.

```
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit;
}

/**
 * @hooked WC_Emails::email_header() Output the email header
 */
do_action( 'woocommerce_email_header', $email_heading, $email ); ?>
<?php echo do_shortcode('[related_products limit="4"]'); ?>

<p><?php _e( "Your order has been received and is now being processed. Your order     details are shown below for your reference:", 'woocommerce' ); ?></p>

<?php

/**
 * @hooked WC_Emails::order_details() Shows the order details table.
 * @hooked WC_Structured_Data::generate_order_data() Generates structured data.
 * @hooked WC_Structured_Data::output_structured_data() Outputs structured data.
 * @since 2.5.0
 */
do_action( 'woocommerce_email_order_details', $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text, $email );

/**
 * @hooked WC_Emails::order_meta() Shows order meta data.
 */
do_action( 'woocommerce_email_order_meta', $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text, $email );

/**
 * @hooked WC_Emails::customer_details() Shows customer details
 * @hooked WC_Emails::email_address() Shows email address
 */
do_action( 'woocommerce_email_customer_details', $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text, $email );

/**
 * @hooked WC_Emails::email_footer() Output the email footer
 */
do_action( 'woocommerce_email_footer', $email );
```

I know that there needs to be a hook or something I can call to display these related products but all i have tried so far are not working or crashing the whole system.

Comment: Did you tried [related_products limit="4"] shortcode?

Comment: yes that didnt work. it just outputs it as plain text.

Comment: will you please share your customer-completed-order.php page code?

Comment: updated the original post

Comment: personally, I would create a hook for it. - like : `add_action( 'woocommerce_email_after_order_table', 'sa_add_related_to_email', 10, 2 );
function sa_add_related_to_email{ //doWhateverHere }`

Comment: But if you're not up for the PHP task, (like getting into the order, choosing a product, and output related products to that product), Then I would probably go with a plugin for customizing emails - like : https://codemiq.com/en/add-related-products-woocommerce-email/

Comment: Thanks Stender!
Btw: related_products wont work at all inside the mail itself but recent_products or something similiar do its job.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code. This may help. Add this code in functions.php file

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_email_after_order_table', 'custom_related_product', 10, 2 );
function custom_related_product( $order, $is_admin_email ) {
    echo do_shortcode('[related_products limit="4"]');
}
```